# Missing internal SD card in /dev/block, phone won't start

Tags: recovery-mode, sd-card, data-recovery, boot, mount

Yesterday my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 froze I'd say. The phone was locked and when I attempted to unlock it, it didn't respond (black display, just the led blinking). So I shut it down with holding power button until it stopped, then tried to power it up. The phone stucked on the Samsung logo booting part.

Currently I can't even get there cleanly, my screen is stucked on the battery image e.g. when you plug in the phone when charging, but the logo is frozen (normally there is a gif showing a charging battery). When I go to recovery and choose to reboot the system (to normal mode, not recovery), I can get pass the battery image, but I'm stuck on the Samsung logo again.

I have Samsung's stock Android 4.4, rooted, with CWM recovery. I can get into the phone when in recovery mode (power+volup+home, `ClockworkMod Recovery v6.0.4.3`), but even through the recovery menu I get only `Can't mount backup path.` or `E:Can't mount /sdcard` when I try to e.g. backup the phone (at least to show whether the damn thing mounts). When I go to the section in CWM where I can attempt to mount (there is format also, but I haven't done it yet, most likely even won't work because of the mounting) these:

- /efs
- /system
- /cache
- /preload
- /data

on each of the options I get only: `Error mounting <...>`.

When I try to wipe the cache, I get this:

> E:format_volume: make_extf4fs failed on /dev/block/mmcblk0p12

When I try wiping dalvik cache, nothing appears in the log.

On each try to actually do something in CWM I get this in the log:

```
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/log
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
```

I can reboot to bootloader, but (perhaps obviously) `adb` doesn't connect to the device because it's not even showing in the list nor able to get it via `adb usb`.

I can get into the phone with `adb` **only when in recovery mode**, so I checked the default locations e.g. `/data/data`, `/sdcard`, `/system` and everything in there seems dead, nothing is mounted.

> /

```
boot                 fstab.smdk4x12       sbin
cache                init                 sd-ext
data                 init.rc              sdcard
datadata             internal_sd          seapp_contexts
default.prop         lpm.rc               sepolicy
dev                  mnt                  storage
efs                  preload              sys
emmc                 proc                 system
etc                  property_contexts    tmp
external_sd          recovery             ueventd.goldfish.rc
file_contexts        res                  ueventd.rc
fstab.goldfish       root                 ueventd.smdk4x12.rc
```

> /dev

```
HPD                    input               ttyGS2
__properties__         ion                 ttyGS3
akm8963                keychord            ttyS0
alarm                  kmem                ttyS1
android_adb            kmsg                ttyS2
ashmem                 link_pm             ttyS3
binder                 log                 ttySAC0
block                  mali                ttySAC1
bus                    mem                 ttySAC2
bus_dma_throughput     mobicore            ttySAC3
console                modem_br            tun
cpu_dma_latency        mtp_usb             tzic
device-mapper          multipdp            uhid
display_frequency      network_latency     uinput
dun                    network_throughput  ump
dvfs_response_latency  null                umts_boot0
ecryptfs               pn544               umts_csd
exynos-mem             ppp                 umts_ipc0
fimg2d                 psaux               umts_loopback0
fmradio                ptmx                umts_ramdump0
full                   pts                 umts_rfs0
fuse                   random              umts_router
graphics               rfkill              urandom
i2c-0                  rtc0                usb_accessory
i2c-1                  rtc1                vcs
i2c-12                 s3c-mem             vcs1
i2c-14                 s3c-mfc             vcsa
i2c-15                 s5p-smem            vcsa1
i2c-17                 snd                 video0
i2c-19                 socket              video1
i2c-21                 srp                 video11
i2c-22                 ssp_sensorhub       video12
i2c-3                  sw_sync             video16
i2c-4                  tspdrv              video2
i2c-5                  tty                 video20
i2c-6                  tty0 - 63           video3
i2c-7                  ttyGS0              xt_qtaguid
i2c-8                  ttyGS1              zero
```

> ~ # ls /dev/block

```
ls /dev/block
loop0       loop4       mmcblk0p12  ram11       ram15       ram5        ram9
loop1       loop5       ram0        ram12       ram2        ram6        vold
loop2       loop6       ram1        ram13       ram3        ram7
loop3       loop7       ram10       ram14       ram4        ram8
```

`mmcblk0p12` is a `/cache` partition, however it's sometimes missing. I don't see the device (`mmcblk0`) there anyway, so perhaps it's just some quirk from CWM. I can't mount it to `/cache` or custom folder too:

> ~ # mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p12 /testfolder

```
mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p12 /testfolder
mount: mounting /dev/block/loop0 on /testfolder failed: Invalid argument
```

I tried to investigate where is the device I'm looking for (`mmcblk0`) and its partitions (mainly `mmcblk0p16` i.e. `/data`) via `dmesg`:

- [dmesg output](https://gist.github.com/KeyWeeUsr/f873d91b8f85e5246cdc5fac5a758b52)(too long for question)

> ~ # cat fstab.goldfish

```
cat fstab.goldfish
# Android fstab file.
#<src>                                                  <mnt_point>         <type>    <mnt_flags and options>                              <fs_mgr_flags>
# The filesystem that contains the filesystem checker binary (typically /system) cannot
# specify MF_CHECK, and must come before any filesystems that do specify MF_CHECK
/dev/block/mtdblock0                                    /system             ext4
      ro,barrier=1                                         wait
/dev/block/mtdblock1                                    /data               ext4
      noatime,nosuid,nodev,barrier=1,nomblk_io_submit      wait,check
/dev/block/mtdblock2                                    /cache              ext4
      noatime,nosuid,nodev,nomblk_io_submit,errors=panic   wait,check
/devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0                        /storage/sdcard     vfat
      defaults                                             voldmanaged=sdcard:auto
```

> ~ # df

```
df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   923748        48    923700   0% /dev
tmpfs                   923748         0    923748   0% /storage
tmpfs                   923748         0    923748   0% /mnt/secure
tmpfs                   923748         0    923748   0% /mnt/fuse
```

> ~ # mount

```
mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,seclabel,relatime)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /storage type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=050,gid=1028)  # this folder is empty actually (bad)
tmpfs on /mnt/secure type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=700)
tmpfs on /mnt/fuse type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=775,gid=1000)
```

> ~ # cat /etc/recovery.fstab

```
# Android fstab file.
#<src>                  <mnt_point>         <type>    <mnt_flags and options>
                            <fs_mgr_flags>
# The filesystem that contains the filesystem checker binary (typically /system) cannot
# specify MF_CHECK, and must come before any filesystems that do specify MF_CHECK
# data partition must be located at the bottom for supporting device encryption

/dev/block/mmcblk0p3     /efs                ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit,errors=panic    wait
/dev/block/mmcblk0p13    /system             ext4      ro,noatime
                                 wait
/dev/block/mmcblk0p12    /cache              ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit,errors=panic    wait,check
/dev/block/mmcblk0p14    /preload            ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit                 wait
/dev/block/mmcblk0p16    /data               ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,discard,noauto_da_alloc,journal_async_commit,errors=panic    wait,check,encryptable=footer

/devices/platform/s3c-sdhci.2/mmc_host/mmc1     /storage/sdcard1    auto      defaults      voldmanaged=sdcard1:auto
/devices/platform/s5p-ehci                     /storage/usbdisk0   auto      defaults      voldmanaged=usbdisk0:auto

# recovery
/dev/block/mmcblk0p8            /boot                           emmc
defaults                recoveryonly
/dev/block/mmcblk0p9            /recovery                       emmc
defaults                recoveryonly
/dev/block/mmcblk0p10           /modem                          emmc
defaults                recoveryonly
```

> ~ # cat /etc/fstab
>   ~ # cat /etc/fstab

```
cat /etc/fstab
/dev/block/mmcblk0p12 /cache ext4 rw
/dev/block/mmcblk0p16 /data ext4 rw
/dev/block/mmcblk0p13 /system ext4 rw
```

I attempted to make a backup via CWM to the **external** card, but it failed I think on the first/fourth step:

```
/storage/sdcard1: Checking
/storage/sdcard1: Mounted
SD Card space free: 14983MB
Backing up boot image...
Error while backing up boot image!
```

Obviously the folder with the backup remains empty.

So to my questions:

1. Is there ***ANY*** way how can I recover data from the internal SD card and/or from the (mounted) `/data` folder? I don't care what happens to the device, I only care about the data.
2. Less important one. Is there any way how to recover the actual system to a working state even without recovering the data mentioned in `1.`?

Edit: Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to me like a lot of `mmcblk0p*` special files are missing under `/dev/block`. I'm not sure on it, but it seems like your internal flash storage is broken.